# How to beat best chess engines?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chess

i am currently learning and practising chess using stockfish engine. When i set the difficulty to maximum, it is impossible to win against these chess engines. Has the machines evolved that far to be intelligent?

I have 2 quick questions for the chess fans here:

1. What are the ways to beat such chess engines?
2. Is there a big difference human playing against human?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to win against a computer if there is still a way to win from the current state (it may depend of the game), but it may be more difficult and the computer can prevent you to win by computing how you could win.

We shouldn't talk about chess : too complicated to understand these questions.
But we could talk about [tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe), it's almost the same.
There is less than !9 (9*8..2*1=362880) move sequences to play this game.
You can build a tree with all these possibilities. If on the branch you are there is a way to a "victory" leaf, you can still win (same for the computer).
There are 3 ways to end a game : victory, defeat and tie.
The game has a finite set of round. So you can compute each move possible (it may be long, but it is possible). Some IA work this way, some only compute a part of this (until the 10th move for instance), much faster.

- What are the ways to beat such engines?

This will seem to be a stupid answer, but you must "just" being better than them. There is no "tutorial" for that. You can also compute further than them (until the 11th move for instance).

- Is there a big difference with human playing?

Yes, machines follow an algorithm, human brain can also follow (simple) one, but often we think differently (with a mix of logic and instinct for instance).

**NB :**

Please note that it is a "simple" answer. There are others, but I think it may be a good beginning.